# Python For Loop List Interesting Result

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for b in a:
  print ":"+str(b)
  a.pop(0)
```

Thinking that this would work in order going through the entire list and all its items I ran this code and expected this.

```
:0
0
:1
1
:2
2
:3
3
:4
4
:5
5
```

Instead I got this:

```
:0
0
:2
1
:4
2
```

Now I understand why this happened but is this an error in python? Shouldn't it still go through all of the original objects instead of the length of the current list? And why did this not throw and out of bounds error?
IE: Shouldn't it still have done:

```
:0
0
:1
2
:2
4
:3
Error
:4
Error
:5
Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over a list and altering it at the same time. By using `.pop()` you are shortening the list, but the iterator pointer is not updated.

Use a copy instead:

```
for b in list(a):
```

or

```
for b in a[:]:
```

where the `[:]` slice notation returns a list copy.

Another approach would be to use a `while` loop instead:

```
while a:
    print a.pop(0)
```

because an empty list tests as boolean `False`.

The python `for` loop uses it's argument as an iterator, it does not itself keep an index. There is no way for the `for` loop to 'know' you removed elements. Instead, it's the `list()` iterator that keeps that pointer:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> itera = iter(a)
>>> itera.next()  # index 0 -> a[0] is 0
0
>>> a.pop(0)
0
>>> a
[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> itera.next()  # index 1 -> a[1] is 2
2
```

That iterator keeps a counter, and every time you call `next()` on the iterator it'll give you the value at the next index, *whatever that value may be*, until the counter is equal to the *current* lenght of the list.

Comment: I already understood why but shouldn't this be throwing an error?

Comment: oh I'm forgetting that the list is shortening but even still its going by the length of the list instead of each element.

Comment: "You cannot loop over a list and alter it at the same time." You can, it just won't work like you might want it to.

Answer (score 5):

This is completely "expected" and documented behavior.  When you iterate over the list, you're basically iterating over memory locations.  When you pop something out of the list, everything after that in the list moves 1 index closer to the start of the list.  Hence, you end up skipping items.  Iteration stops when you reach the end of the list.

Typically when doing something like this, you want to iterate over a copy of the list:

```
for b in a[:]:
    ...
```

As indicated in the comments, if you iterate over the list in reversed order:

```
for b in reversed(a):
    a.pop()
```

This works as intended because you are constantly pulling off the final element and therefore you're not shifting the position in the list of any of the elements that you haven't yet seen.

Comment: Another useful approach in some situations is to iterate in reverse order: `for b in reversed(a)`

Comment: @kindall -- Thanks for the comment.  I've incorporated that information into my answer.

Comment: -1 is the default argument for `.pop()` so you can omit it safely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- `try: Make_me_feel_better_argument("Explicit is better than implicit"); except FeelBetterError: update_post()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.pop()` in a loop, a common idiom is to use it with `while`:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
while a:
  print ":{}".format(a.pop(0))
```

Or, if you want the printed pattern you have there:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
while a:
    print ":{}\n{}".format(a[0],a.pop(0))
```

prints

```
:0
0
:1
1
:2
2
:3
3
:4
4
:5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the `for` loop we have to check the condition `b in a` So when you start:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for b in a:
  print ":"+str(b)
  a.pop(0)
```

`b = 0` and `in a` (meaning elements in a) is `5`. Now you print the stringified version of `a[b]` then remove the first element of the array. Thus iteration two becomes:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = 1 (it incremented)
size of a = 4 (it shrank)
```

Next they'll be `b=2`, size of a becomes 3. The final iteration which would have produced the out of bounds errors you were expecting, won't occur then because `b` will be larger than the size of the array, so we're done.